# call one function within another function in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, function

is there a way to call function within another function eg:

```
call functionname()
```

but this can be called only within the sub, is there a round about?,
I have tried using GOTO but even that should be within the same sub or function.

Comment: there are a couple of vb.net answers given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do this

```
public void myfunc()
{
}

public void callerOfMyFunc()
{
    myFunc();
}
```

I think you might want to read up a little about [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

> A method is a code block that contains a series of statements. A
>   program causes the statements to be executed by calling the method and
>   specifying any required method arguments. In C#, every executed
>   instruction is performed in the context of a method. The Main method
>   is the entry point for every C# application and it is called by the
>   common language runtime (CLR) when the program is started.

Even for VB you can look at [Sub Procedures (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831f9wka.aspx)

> A Sub procedure is a series of Visual Basic statements enclosed by the
>   Sub and End Sub statements. The Sub procedure performs a task and then
>   returns control to the calling code, but it does not return a value to
>   the calling code.
>
> Each time the procedure is called, its statements are executed,
>   starting with the first executable statement after the Sub statement
>   and ending with the first End Sub, Exit Sub, or Return statement
>   encountered.
>
> You can define a Sub procedure in modules, classes, and structures. By
>   default, it is Public, which means you can call it from anywhere in
>   your application that has access to the module, class, or structure in
>   which you defined it. The term, method, describes a Sub or Function
>   procedure that is accessed from outside its defining module, class, or
>   structure. For more information, see Procedures in Visual Basic.
>
> A Sub procedure can take arguments, such as constants, variables, or
>   expressions, which are passed to it by the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub DoSomething
    OtherFunction()
End Sub

Public Sub OtherFunction()
    'Do something here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Function MethodOne() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False

    ' Do something 

    Return result
End Function

Function MethodTwo() As Boolean
    ' Call Method One
    Dim res As Boolean = MethodOne()

    Return res
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function MethodOne() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False

    ' Do something 

    Return result
End Function

Function MethodTwo() As Boolean
    ' Call Method One
    Dim res As Boolean = MethodOne()
End Function
```